# git multiple pull requests

Tags: github, branch, pull-request

I'm a git noob in a shared environment, but have used it for personal projects fine.

I'm trying to contribute to a project, so I did this:

- Forked the project.
- Made code changes.
- Committed code changes to my local branch.
- Pushed changes to my fork
- Did a pull request.

That worked great. PR is still pending, but I had some other ideas.
So, I created a new local branch.

- Made code changes
- Committed code changes to local branch
- Pushed changes to my forked copy
- Did a PR

The code changes from my previous edits are obviously in place with this PR. I do not want that, since they haven't been committed to the main branch.
Likewise, I want to make additional changes and push them specifically without containing the code from my previous work.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already started a second pull request, you'll have to forego best practices:

1. rebase your local `<PR-2-branch>` to start of PR-1 (say 8 commits ago). use `-i` to start an interactive session.

   ```
   git rebase -i HEAD~8
   ```
2. In the editor window that opens up, hit <kbd>i</kbd> and mark commits from PR-1 (5 commits) to be `drop` or `d` and `pick` or `p` commits from PR-2 (3 commits)

   ```
   d 113456 <message>
   d 223456 <message>
   d 333456 <message>
   d 443456 <message>
   d 553456 <message>
   p 663456 <message>
   p 773456 <message>
   p 883456 <message>
   ```

   Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> > <kbd>w</kbd> > <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the editor and to proceed with the `rebase`.
   The branch now contains only commits within the scope of current PR.
3. Update the remote branch with `--force`

   ```
   git push origin <PR-2-branch> --force
   ```